# How to return two different classes from single method

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
public ResponseEntity<Profile> getProfile(@PathVariable("id") String id){
    if(id != null){
    //getting CUSTOMER from DB
    returning EntityProfile

    if(CUSTOMER == null)
    //getting data from webservice
    returning Profile
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's your question exactly? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can return two different *objects* from a method by encapsulating them in a single class representing the return value of the method. You'll also need to use Java syntax. There is no keyword `returning`.

Comment: If `EntityProfile extends Profile`, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Create a REST layer  `Profile` object and convert your inner objects to your REST object.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using Generics. You haven't explained the relation between the `Profile` and `EntityProfile`. So, assuming you have something called  `BaseProfile` and these 2 Profile objects extends them, you can write the return type as:

```
public ResponseEntity <? extends BaseProfile>
```

This way you can return any object of type BaseProfile.

If `Profile` is a parent class of `EntityProfile`, your code (`public ResponseEntity <Profile>`) should work fine. However, if you want to return any type of object, you could change the return type as:

```
 public ResponseEntity <?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a new class which contains an EntityProfile property and a Profile property:

```
public class CombinedClass{
     EntityProfile entity;
     Profile profile;
}
```

Then make your method return a CombinedClass with the class you need to return. Then on your receiving end, you just need to check if entity or profile are null before trying to get the data.

```
public ResponseEntity<CombinedClass> getProfile(@PathVariable("id") String id){
    CombinedClass combined = new CombinedClass();
    if(id != null){
        combined.EntityProfile = //the EntityProfile you'll return
    }
    if(CUSTOMER == null){
        combined.profile= //the Profile you'll return
    }
    return combined;
}
```

A little more code could help to understand how you'd need it though.